# how to show keyboard programatically in windows phone 8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I have an issue with windows 10 phone that keyboard is not appearing after third tap on textbox . I need a method so that I can enable keyboard forcefully.

Comment: Are you having the issue with Windows phone 8 or Windows 10 mobile?

Comment: I am having issue with Windows phone 10 only.

Comment: So the project is UWP?

Comment: yes.. There is no problem for windows phone 8 . issue started when i upgraded my device to latest version of windows phone 10

Comment: Did you try the emulator if it works there?

Comment: I have tried it on device only .I don't have windows phone 10 sdk